# Is there a way to manually delete a page and then navigate to it and reinitialize it again using ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
        For example i am displaying a home page after login.

        In the Home screen i have a menu in that menu i have options as  New Flight,Home.

        When i click on the home button i will load Home Screen only.
        For that i am using navctrl.push(HomePage). Every time user clicks that button
        it is adding the same page multiple time into the navigation stack.

        can you please tell me how to solve this problem.whenever user clicks the Home Button it want to remove the previous home page and newly it want to add the Home page.how can i achieve this?
```

The below is the my component.ts file code

- List item

  ```
      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
      import { IonicPage, Nav, NavParams, App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
      import { NewflightPage } from '../newflight/newflight';
      import { RolesactionPage } from '../rolesaction/rolesaction';
      import { EditProfilePage } from '../edit-profile/edit-profile';
      import { ManagePeoplePage } from '../manage-people/manage-people';
      import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
      @IonicPage()
      @Component({
        selector: 'page-main',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
      })

      export class MainPage {
        constructor(public navCtrl: Nav, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController,public appCtrl: App) {
        }


        ionViewWillEnter() {
          var lc = document.createElement('script');
          lc.type = 'text/javascript';
          lc.src = 'assets/js/dialog.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);

        }
        rolesAction() {
          this.navCtrl.push(RolesactionPage);
        }
        myFlightAction() {
          this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);

        }         
      }


  Above is the my component code.

  I am calling myFlightAction()  from main.html like below

   <a (click)="myFlightAction()"><img src="assets/imgs/flight-depart.png" alt="My Flights"> My Flights</a>
  ```

  please tell me where i am wrong.when i check in the browser by inspecting it is adding newly as z-index 101 ... like that every time.when i click the my flight button.
  can you please also tell me how to load the java script files required for each ionic page individually every time when that page loads?

Comment: probably something is wrong in your menu code or your app.components code. Please share some code so we can help.

Comment: I have edited my question with my component code in the above.please check once.Also one more doubt how do i include the js files for each and every components individually when component loads?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that you're pushing a new page, this way it'll always have a new page without dismissing the last one. What you have to do for this case is use `setRoot` method.

```
myFlightAction() {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(MainPage);
}
```

Be warned that this'll clear your navigation stack and set the `MainPage` as your first page.

Pushing a page simply puts another page in the navigation stack, this is why it gives an `z-index` of a higher value for every page you push. While `setRoot`, as the name implies, sets the [root component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#setRoot) of your navigation stack to the component you want.

### Edit - Without removing the Login Page from the Stack.

You'll need to know what's the index of the page you're in so you can remove it from the stack. Since i don't know the order of the pages and how can the access each other or even if the order can be dynamic, we'll first get the page controller so e can get his index, then push another page and after that you'll remove the previous one.

```
myFlightAction() {
  // Get the controller of the active page
  const myActualController = this.navCtrl.getActive();
  // Get the index of the active page
  const pageIndex: number = this.navCtrl.indexOf(myActualController);
  // Push your new page
  this.navCtrl.push(MainPage).then(() => {
    // In the callback of your push method, after successfully pushing your the page, you'll remove this page based on his index.
    this.navCtrl.remove(pageIndex);
  });
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between pushing the new page using push and set root method?can you explain  once

Comment: I have tried with setRoot it is working but the problem is when i hit the back button it is not working .it is not going to login page.It is closing the application with out going to login screen.

Comment: But why you would want the user to go to the login page after it's already loged? When the user logs the default behaviour is to the home page be the root component, going back to login page is bad. What you can do is using a logout button that sets the root to the login page, but i'll update with another option so you can mantain tha behaviour.

Comment: can you tell me the difference between push and setroot.when to use push and setroot?

Comment: @subbu edited the question, if you want to let the login page remains as the root page use the second code.

Comment: if we use the second page is there any other way to remove the view from navigation stack

Comment: can you please tell me how to include the custom javascript file for each component?the way which i have specified in the ionviewwillenter(){} is correct?

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to do this, search about thrid party scripts. Also ionViewWillEnter fires every time you enter the page, so if you go to another page and then comes back to that page this lifecycle hook fires again, for this case maybe the correct is `ionViewWillLoad()` since it fires only when the page is loaded.

Comment: i have one more small doubt in the second code which you have mentioned.In that can we change like below 1.First we will remove the page then we will push the page is that possible.if it possible can you please give the code how i can do that

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing, but i remove the active page after i push the new page. If you do the other way around the user'll see the moment the page is removed and the other is pushed.

Comment: thank you.can you please tell me how to load the css for each component when it view loading

Comment: @subbu this is really basics structure for ionic pages, search the docs because your question turned out to be lots of different questions and should be separatted in different questions. If my answer helped you please accept it as correct so it can help other people too. Thanks